# accelerometer android query

Tags: android, accelerometer

i need to develop an app that needs data from the accelerometer. could some one please suggest which android phone in the market would be good enough for accurate accelerometer data generator. since the entire app is based on data fetched by the accelerometer, the device has to be pretty accurate.

Comment: a good example here, may help some one http://www.quicktips.in/get-accelerometer-readings-android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accelerometers in any smart phone are cheap and the difference in the accuracy of the readings is negligible. Even though these devices are cheap, they're very accurate and can output a few thousand readings per second - so the accuracy of your program is going to be dependent on what you DO with the readings in your code not by the device itself.

If you just want an Android phone for development - not to use with a wireless plan, then go to ebay and swoop a used one up for $30-40. Most of these phones have accelerometers in them, but before you buy it - google the model and make sure.

I own a G1 - the original Android phone, and the accelerometer is very accurate.

Comment: I've never personally seen accelerometers output several thousand times per second through the android `SensorManager` API on the fastest setting. Maybe a hundred.

Comment: @Jon - Hmmm, I haven't clocked readings on Android, but I've used some cheap accelerometers with micro-controllers(Arduino) in a robotics project and those clock at about 2500-3000 per second. I wonder if the Android OS is governing it?

Comment: .. Thanks! That really helps. By reading your last comment, I understand that you are into developing app for a research project.If that's true, have you ever worked on a "wocket"? A small sensor developed by MIT students http://wockets.wikispaces.com/. please let me know

Comment: @raqz - I haven't worked with Wocket, but I have used a MIT library called "Amarino" which is used to connect an Android device to a microcontroller with a bluetooth module (ArduinoBT). It's Pretty neat, you can operate robots, RC cars, etc.. with an interface built in an Android App.